# why would you need to specify a language in a HTML hyperlink?

Tags: html

this is an example code, where I have seen the language of the link being specified, what difference does this make?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>How to create a hyperlink</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://w3resource.com" hreflang="en">w3resource Tutorial</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a meta attribute that has no meaning. It is purely advisory. For HTML5, the allowed values are outlined in [BCP47](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt).

Comment: sorry I'm still an absolute beginner, what is a meta attribute?

Comment: @Mohamed Hegazy: Metadata are bits of information about data.

Comment: @MohamedHegazy Basically it means it makes no difference except to user agents who care about it, like say a user agent that displays a preview page translated (purely hypothetical)

Comment: No. `charset="utf-8"` determines the encoding of the page. If the actual encoding does not match the declared encoding, your document will not display correctly.

Comment: @user6160478 "user agent that displays a preview page translated" ... Actually, no. See my answer for the W3C HTML5 spec which says such a user agent must determine the language of the document from the document itself upon fetching it for translation.

Answer (score 1):

See [hreflang](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#attr-hyperlink-hreflang) in HTML5:

> The hreflang attribute on [`a`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) and [`area`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-area-element) elements that create hyperlinks, if present, gives the language of the linked resource. It is purely advisory. The value must be a valid [BCP 47 language tag](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt). ***User agents must not consider this attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must use only language information associated with the resource to determine its language, not metadata included in the link to the resource.*** (emphasis added)

You can also use `hreflang` in the `<head>` of the document:

> If the `alternate` keyword is used with the `hreflang` attribute, and that attribute's value differs from the root element's language, it indicates that the referenced document is a translation.

See [`<link rel="alternate">`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate).

[Google allows webmasters to use `hreflang` attributes on `link` elements](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) to point to translated versions of a web site:

> Imagine you have an English language page hosted at `http://www.example.com/`, with a Spanish alternative at `http://es.example.com/`. You can indicate to Google that the Spanish URL is the Spanish-language equivalent of the English page ...:
>
> > ... In the HTML `<head>` section of `http://www.example.com/`, add a link element pointing to the Spanish version of that webpage at `http://es.example.com/`, like this:
> >
> > ```
> > <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />
> > ```